# Solr DataImportHandler, Multiple documents

Tags: solr, lucene, dih

I am very new to `Solr`...

I need to Import data from a DB with different contexts (`schemas`).
and I want to be able to search for both of those documents using a single query.

I did some reading, and I am a bit confused...

since I understand the `DataImportHandler` will read only the first document tag. 
I don't know how to define another document.

what will be the best approach to achieve that.

can you help please to clean up the mist.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can have two succesive `<document>` tags and solr will execute both.

If you can get by this way (not sure what db are you using, so not sure if you can specify the schema part in the SELECT of each document tag).

If the above is not possible you can always use two different `db-data-config.xml` (and two different endpoints of course), each one targeting one db/schema. But be warned:

- you cannot use `&clean=true` in both as your existing docs will be wiped, you need to do it explicitly on the beggining only.
- delta indexing gets more complex too.